# Convert PostgreSQL JSONB column results for use in condition with IN

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a table with a JSONB column that is used to store multiple tags (integer) that have been applied to a task, eg.: `'[123, 456, 789]'`.

```
ALTER TABLE "public"."task" ADD COLUMN "tags" jsonb;
```

I also have a table dedicated to storing all the tags that can be used, and the primary key of each record is used in my JSONB column of the task table.

```
CREATE TABLE public.tag (
    tag_id serial NOT NULL,
    label varchar(50) NOT NULL,
);
```

In this table (tag) I have an index based on the task ID, and I want to use this index in a query that returns the tags labels that were used in a task.

```
SELECT * FROM task, tag WHERE task.tags @> to_jsonb(tag.tag_id)
```

Using `to_jsonb` is really bad as it doesn't use my table's index, but if I change the SQL to something like the example below, the index is used and SQL performance is much better.

```
SELECT * FROM tag WHERE tag.tag_id IN (123, 456, 789)
```

How do I convert the jsonb column (task table) to a set of integer values ​​that can be used with the `IN` condition, as in the example below?

```
SELECT * FROM task, tag WHERE tag.tag_id IN (task.tags);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PostgreSQL `jsonb_array_elements` function which convert JSON elements to table records. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM task, tag WHERE tag.tag_id in (
    select jsonb_array_elements('[200, 100, 789]'::jsonb)::int4 as json_data
);
```

But, for best performance, if you get JSON data from the table fields, so you must index this JSON field not use the standard `btree` index type. For JSON types PostgreSQL has a different index type as `GIN` index. This index type will give the best performance. I use this index in my table which has a million records. Very very best performance. Example for creating `GIN` index:

```
CREATE INDEX tag_table_json_index ON tag_table USING gin (json_field_name jsonb_path_ops);
```

Comment: "*if you get JSON data from the table fields, so you must index this JSON field*" - I think OP is concerned with using the index on `tag.tag_id`, which should work fine with your query.

Comment: Yes, `tag.tag_id` also must be indexed for performance. And you also need to consider that, if the result of the query which the inside `IN` command will be large (for example million records) then recommended using `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN` command for best performance.